# issue when downloading a text file in R

Tags: r

I want to download a text from Project Gutenberg and I have done the following code:

```
setwd("D:\\sourceCode")
TEXTFILE = "pg100.txt"
if (!file.exists(TEXTFILE)) {
    download.file("http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/100/pg100.txt", destfile = TEXTFILE)
}
shakespeare = readLines(TEXTFILE)
```

The problem that I have is that I got the following messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In readLines(TEXTFILE) : invalid or incomplete compressed data
2: In readLines(TEXTFILE) : incomplete final line found on 'pg100.txt'
```

Actually I am following the tutorial that is in:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/text-mining-the-complete-works-of-william-shakespeare/

Then when I want to get the length of the document with:

length(shakespeare)

The data I get is:

```
[1] 55
```

but according to the tutorial that I gave the link before, the data should be:

```
[1] 124787
```

what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I am however on a Mac.

Comment: No error for me either. I'm on Linux

Comment: I got the same error. Only 55 lines. I m using on windows.

Comment: The downloaded file is a `gzip` archive. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The downloaded file is  a `gzip` archive not a txt file.

Either unzip manually, or do

```
TEXTFILE = "pg100.txt.gz"
if (!file.exists(TEXTFILE)) {
    download.file("http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/100/pg100.txt", destfile = 
TEXTFILE)
}
shakespeare = readLines(gzfile(TEXTFILE))
head(shakespeare)
#[1] "The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Complete Works of William Shakespeare, by"
#[2] "William Shakespeare"
#[3] ""
#[4] "This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with"
#[5] "almost no restrictions whatsoever.  You may copy it, give it away or"
#[6] "re-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included"

length(shakespeare)
#[1] 124787
```

---

### Update

In Windows it seems that you need to set an explicit binary transfer mode (since the file in question is not a text file but a binary archive):

```
TEXTFILE = "pg100.txt.gz"
if (!file.exists(TEXTFILE)) {
    download.file("http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/100/pg100.txt", destfile = 
TEXTFILE, mode = "wb")
}
shakespeare = readLines(gzfile(TEXTFILE))
```

Comment: Are you sure this grabs everything? When I tried this, it only grabbed the first 54 lines, whereas the file has over 120k lines. The command-line `gunzip` reports that this file is invalid and doesn't uncompress very far. I think you need `mode="wb"` as ddunn801 has in their answer. (I'm on win10 if it makes a difference.)

Comment: @r2evans Yes it seems to grab everything (see the updated `length(shakespeare)`). I didn't use `mode="wb"`. Do you still get an incomplete file if you copy & paste my answer?

Comment: Nope, I get length 54, so it must be a windows thing, default to non-binary file writes. From `?download.file`: *Since Windows (unlike Unix-alikes) does distinguish between text and binary files, care is needed that other binary file types are transferred with 'mode = "wb"'.* (I just found that.)

Comment: @r2evans I see & interesting. I didn't know about the difference between text and binary files when transferring files on Windows machines. Reminds me of the `ftp` binary and ASCII transfer modes...

Comment: @Little Did you try the solution from my update? Even with `mode = "wb"` you will still need to use `readLines(gzfile(...))` since the file in question is *not* a text file.

Answer (score 2):

Just include the `mode` parameter as so:

```
download.file("http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/100/pg100.txt", destfile = TEXTFILE, mode = "wb")
```

Comment: still got the same problem, I am on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to read a file from http://www.gutenberg.org you can use the `gutenbergr` package. The tutorial you are pointing to is quite old and the package did not exist when it was written. The advantage of the package is that you do not run into downloading / readLines issues depending on your operating system.

```
library(gutenbergr)

# if you know which gutenberg id it is. (EBook-No. on gutenberg website)
# otherwise use other gutenbergr code to find authors and works. See vignette for more info

# complete works of Shakespeare is EBook-No. 100
shakespeare <- gutenberg_download(100) 

head(shakespeare)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  gutenberg_id text                                                             
         <int> <chr>                                                            
1          100 Shakespeare                                                      
2          100 ""                                                               
3          100 *This Etext has certain copyright implications you should read!* 
4          100 ""                                                               
5          100 <<THIS ELECTRONIC VERSION OF THE COMPLETE WORKS OF WILLIAM       
6          100 SHAKESPEARE IS COPYRIGHT 1990-1993 BY WORLD LIBRARY, INC., AND IS
```